# System reports unexpected shutdown when shutdown properly. How to debug/Where to start?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running windows server 2008 R2. When I shutdown my server, it appears to shutdown correctly.

But, when it boots up it prompts me about an unexpected shutdown. I don't have any minidumps and I can't find anything helpful in the event viewer. I do see a Kernel-Power event saying the system shutdown unexpectedly.

That said, if anyone has any suggestions about what to search for in the event viewer, I'm open to giving it a try.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you shutting it down? If it's via the command line/batch file, are you setting a reason code? (see `shutdown /?`)

Comment: I'm shutting it down from the start menu. But maybe some other software is getting in the way(?)